# r markdown document - error about character options, but not seeing the mistake

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am probably missing something simple here.  When I run code in an R markdown code cell, it throws this error:

```
(*) NOTE: I saw chunk options " dataFrames, echo=TRUE eval=TRUE"
 please go to http://yihui.name/knitr/options
 (it is likely that you forgot to quote "character" options)
```

Here is the code from the cell that triggered the error:

````
```{r dataFrames, echo=TRUE eval=TRUE}

df1 <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3),
                 c("R","S","T"),
                 c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
```
````

I tried the link given in the error, but did not run across anything that explained the glitch for me.  Can anyone spot it?

Comment: I think you need to add a comma at the start: ```{r dataFrames, echo=TRUE, eval=TRUE}```

Comment: You are right.  I think I was answering this and you were commenting on it at the exact same moment about 32 minutes ago.  realized my mistake shortly after putting the post.

Comment: If anyone else comes across this, it can also be caused by saying something like `out.width=50%` instead of `out.width='50%'` (with quotes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just noticed what appears to be the problem.  Forgot a comma between the last two arguments as in:

````
```{r dataFrames, echo=TRUE, eval=TRUE}
````

not:

````
```{r dataFrames, echo=TRUE eval=TRUE}
````

oops.

Adding this in from the comments: If anyone else comes across this, it can also be caused by saying something like `out.width=50%` instead of `out.width='50%'` (with quotes).

Comment: I have run into this error when I use reserved words as part of my labels. For example, I had a chunk with the label choose-xray-function (this chunk contained a function to choose a certain x-ray for analysis). Without qoutes around the label, I received the error cited above. If I either put the label in quotes: label = "choose-xray-function", or dropped the word function (label = choose-xray) then everything worked as expected. 

I guess it makes sense - but it was a head-scratcher for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to note that I also came across this issue when using a single apostrophe in the name of my chunk

i.e.:

`{r Chronbach's Alpha}` throws the error, but `{r Chronbachs Alpha}` does not.